# my ViewPage does not work correctly in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Strange problem 
I Use frame layout and inside it I use Some Fragment Like Below And Handle Fragment With Bottom Bar

Now in One Of These Fragment I Use ViewPager And TabLayout Like Below

My Problem Is when Change Fragment From for exmple first  to Third 
First time change correctly but for 
second time it does not work correctly and some thing happened like below

This is code for third Fragment Load (Just Load ViewPager)

```
public class Social extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private BestMonth b,b1;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Social() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    b= new BestMonth();

    b1= new BestMonth();
}


/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment Social.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Social newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Social fragment = new Social();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_social, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setupTabIcons();

    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


private void setupTabIcons() {

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("برترین های ماه");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText("محمبوب ترین ها");

    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(b, "بهترین ها");
    adapter.addFragment(b1, "برترین ها");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

And This Fragment Load Content Of ViewPager Inside Third Fragment

```
public class BestMonth extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;


private List<SocialInsClass> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PostAdapter mAdapter;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


public BestMonth() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BestMonth newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BestMonth fragment = new BestMonth();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_best_month, container, false);

    view = Init(view);

    return view;
}


private void prepareMovieData() {
    movieList.clear();
    SocialInsClass movie = new SocialInsClass("آرش", "https://ig-s-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/17267780_1886609681623949_4740572605386326016_a.jpg", "گل من", "http://nargil.ir/plant/images/pic/978/Armeria%20Maritima712.jpg");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new SocialInsClass("راضیه", "https://ig-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/14134653_740842746053754_866503745_a.jpg", " قابل شما رو ندار", "http://nargil.ir/plant/images/pic/978/Armeria%20Maritima308.jpg");
    movieList.add(movie);


    movie = new SocialInsClass("یگانه", "https://ig-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/17663339_736255433209640_3627796035541139456_a.jpg", "گل دون منزل من", "http://nargil.ir/plant/images/pic/978/Armeria%20Maritima953.jpg");
    movieList.add(movie);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private View Init(View view) {


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_views);
    floatingActionButton= (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.post);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SendPost.class));

        }
    });


    mAdapter = new PostAdapter(movieList, getActivity());

    prepareMovieData();


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




    return view;
}




// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Thank You So Much For Your Guide

:)

[1) First Fragment 2) Third Fragment I am Using ViePager In It(Load Correctly) 3)When Choose in second time and does not work corectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urCEA.jpg)